# How to fill MDIForm with default content in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created MDIForm that contains some child forms. Now i want to load some default content in MDIForm because without any content it is not looks good while opening MDIForm just like
[image: Image1].
When i tried to make some contents in MDIForm then the child form are behind the controls like
[image].

I tried load a child form in MDIParent form but it occurs some issues like i set form border style none, but it display minimize, maximize and close buttons. It affects on my designing & controls position too, but i can manage it using dock/anchor but the problem is form border style(as you can see in image2).

So please someone tell me that **what is the right way to do this**?

I hope you understand what i want to say. If you have doubt then you can ask me about that.

Comment: do you try to create some sort of dashboard on top of which all the children will open?

Comment: Any controls that you put on the parent that overlap the MDI client window (the one with the dark gray background) will always overlap the child windows as well.  You must put them on a panel that you dock to a side so the client window shrinks.

Comment: what does not look good in image1 ?

Comment: Nice freeform selection you got there :] With all seriousness @HansPassant is right. Try his suggestion

Comment: Yeah, that's good suggestion thanks Hans & Nobody. And Guido i want load default data there, but in image 1 it looks empty. And answer of CynicalSection is 'yes' i want to do as you say.